# Как правильно распарсить коммандную строку Java

Tags: java, консоль

Допустим есть строка, которая приходит в `String[] args`. Например:

```
file --db.txt add firstname --Name lastname --Surname age --33 address --Street
```

Не понимаю, как ее распарсить так, чтобы файл и его имя были, как "глобальные параметры", команда `add` (или `update`, или `delete` и т.д) могла использоваться для реализации конкретной логики, а остальная часть строки - "локальные параметры" модели... Попытался сделать так:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);
    Map<String, String> params = new Main().parse(args);
    AddCommand add = new AddCommand();
    add.execute(params);
}

private Map<String, String> parse(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2){
        if (i + 1 < args.length){
            parameters.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}}
```

Имеется интерфейс, содержащий метод для обработки команды:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute(Map<String, String> options);
}
```

Конечно же есть класс самой модели `Person` со всеми Getters and Setters and toString() и класс `DataFile`, где, собственно, происходит сохранение в текстовый файл и в Json.

Но, наверное это неправильный путь... В этой реализации я не могу выделить саму команду (`add`, `update`, `find`, `delete`). Подскажите пожалуйста правильный путь.

Comment: А не проще использовать какой-нить CLI http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поддерживаю @SerhiiDikobrazko, рекомендую [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет! Помогло.) Правда, пока не получается корректно реализовать логику для команд update и delete. Может что-то сможете по этому поводу подсказать?..

Comment: Это [Usage Scenarios](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) не поможет?

Comment: О! Сейчас посмотрю...

Answer (score 1):

Не изобретайте велосипед, возьмите [готовое, проверенное решение](https://picocli.info/)